# create fixed length flat file with Java

Tags: java, web-applications, export, flat-file

I have a process that currently runs in a Delphi application that I wrote and I need to convert it to a Java process that will run on our web application.  Basically our State Financial (legacy) system requires this file in a specific output.  In Delphi it is like this:

```
procedure CreateSHAREJournalFile(AppDate : string; ClassCode : string; BudgetRef : String; AccountNumber : string; FYEStep : integer);
var
GLFileInfo : TStrings;
MPayFormat, HPayFormat, TPayFormat : string;
const
//this is the fixed length format for each item in the file
HeaderFormat = '%-1s%-5s%-10s%-8s%-12s%-10s%-21s%-3s%-71s%-3s%-20s%-1s';
DetailFormat = '%-1s%-5s%-9s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-8s%-6s%-5s%-5s%-5s%-8s%-25s%-10s%-60s%-28s%-66s%-28s';
begin
  try
//get the data from the query
    with dmJMS.qryShare do
    begin
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('SELECT SUM(TOTHRPAY) As HourPay, SUM(TOTMLPAY) As MilePay, SUM(TOTALPAY) AS TotalPay FROM JMPCHECK INNER JOIN JMPMAIN ON JMPCHECK.JURNUM = JMPMAIN.JURNUM WHERE PANELID LIKE ''' + Copy(AppDate, 3, 6) + '%'' ');
      if FYEStep > -1 then
        SQL.Add('AND WARRANTNO = ' + QUotedStr(IntToStr(FYEStep)));
      Active := True;
//assign totals to variables so they can be padded with leading zeros
    MPayFormat := FieldByName('MilePay').AsString;
    while length(MPayFormat) < 28 do <br>MPayFormat := '0' + MPayFormat;
    HPayFormat := FieldByName('HourPay').AsString;
    while length(HPayFormat) < 28 do <br>HPayFormat := '0' + HPayFormat;
    TPayFormat := Format('%f' ,[(FieldByName('TotalPay').AsCurrency)]);
    while length(TPayFormat) < 27 do
    TPayFormat := '0' + TPayFormat;
    TPayFormat := '-' + TPayFormat;
//create a TStringlist to put each line item into
    GLFileInfo := TStringList.Create;
//add header info using HeaderFormat defined above
    GLFileInfo.Add(Format(HeaderFormat, ['H', '21801', 'NEXT', FormatDateTime('MMDDYYYY', Today), '', 'ACTUALS', '', 'EXT', '', 'EXT', '', 'N']));
//add detail info using DetailFormat defined above
    GLFileInfo.Add(Format(DetailFormat, ['L', '21801', '1', 'ACTUALS', AccountNumber, '', '1414000000', '111500', '', '01200', ClassCode, '', BudgetRef, '', AccountNumber + '0300', '', MPayFormat, '', MPayFormat]));
    GLFileInfo.Add(Format(DetailFormat, ['L', '21801', '2', 'ACTUALS', AccountNumber, '', '1414000000', '111500', '', '01200', ClassCode, '', BudgetRef, '', AccountNumber + '0100', '', HPayFormat, '', HPayFormat]));
    GLFileInfo.Add(Format(DetailFormat, ['L', '21801', '3', 'ACTUALS', '101900', '', '1414000000', '111500', '', '01200', ClassCode, '', BudgetRef, '', '', '', TPayFormat, '', TPayFormat]));
//save TStringList to text file
    GLFileINfo.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'FileTransfer\GL_' + formatdateTime('mmddyy', Today) + SequenceID + '24400' + '.txt');
    end;
  finally
    GLFileINfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Is there an equivalent in Java for the Format option?  Or the TStringList that saves to a text file?

Thanks for any information....haven't done a lot of Java programming!

Leslie

Comment: I found this link but don't see how you format the output:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0461.html

Comment: For future reference, that's not how you encode code blocks on Stackoverflow. Just indent all the code by 4 spaces.

Comment: thanks for the info!  I tried all kinds of things to get it to look right!  thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all relatively simple operations in Java (or a lot of other languages, for that matter).
For your use case in Java, it's probably easiest to access the database directly via JDBC, as shown [here](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/). After you retrieve the data, you can use [String.format(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to format the data the way you need it and you can then write it to a file (as described [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml)).

Comment: Yes I know they are simple operations, but when you're not sure what to search on it makes it difficult to find the answers!  Thanks for the links especially the String.format!

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :)